# Background Image color losing in UIToolbar

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, uitoolbar

I have two images an arrow and a bar image

image1===>An arrow

[image]

The orginal color values of this arrow is shown below

[image]

image2===>The Bar

[image]
The orginal color values  of bar are shown below.

[image]

I am loading the barImage   in the toolbar with the following code and showing the arrow just above it.

```
 bottomBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,974,931,54)];
[bottomBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bottomBar.png"]
           forToolbarPosition:UIBarPositionAny
                   barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Now the bar image is loosing its orginal color as shown below.

[image]

The new color values are

[image]
[image]

The bar button lost its orginal color. Can anyone suggest me a work around?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
[bottomBar setTranslucent:NO]
```

UIToolbar's translucency set to YES by default.